# Using Kendo-Spreadsheet with angular 6

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, kendospreadsheet

I want to implement Kendo-Spreadsheet with Angular 6.
I have found few examples where people has shown how to use Kendo-Spreadsheet with AngularJS but didn't found any blog or anything for Angular2+.

Want to know if KenoUI has support for Spreadsheet with Angular 6.

Can you please provide any example to integrate it with Angular 2+

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

There is no Kendo UI for Angular Spreadsheet component, but you can use the Kendo UI for jQuery one in an Angular 6 application as described in [this documentation article](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/framework/kendo-jquery/).